# C#, React, Getting data from a JSON file

Tags: c#, reactjs, json, fetch

I'm pretty new to C# development and I'm trying to get data from a JSON file to show on a React page for a portfolio site. I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://gkoutr.com/2020/04/18/build-your-own-portfolio-resume-website-in-net-core-and-react/) for the C# portion,I plan on completely redoing the React & CSS portion to fit how I want it to look (already changed the react class component to a functional one), but when going to the /aboutMe URL, it was blank. I can't seem to figure out how to make the fetch request to work with the Controller, I've looked it up and found different ways of writing the controller which would negate the need for a JSON file, but I was wondering if there was advise to make it work with the JSON file.

EDIT: The api/aboutMe URL loads the API, but the data from the API is not being submitted into the React Component.

Any help/advise would be appreciated.

I have a Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PortfolioSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PortfolioSite.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/aboutMe")]
    public class AboutController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public AboutMe GetAboutInfo()
        {
            string jsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./Data/AboutMe.json");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AboutMe>(jsonText);
        }
    }
}
```

A Model:

```
using System;

namespace PortfolioSite.Models
{
    public class AboutMe
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Location { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The react component:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import {
    Row, Col, Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
    CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button
} from 'reactstrap';

const AboutMe = () => {

    const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

    const fetchData =()=> {
        fetch("api/aboutMe")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(res => setTitle(res.title))
            .then(res => setName(res.name))
            .then(res => setLocation(res.location))
            .then(res => setDescription(res.description))
            .catch(err => setErrors(err));
    }

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchData();
        },[]);
        
    return (
        <div style={{ padding: "15px" }}>
            <Row>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <img style={{ height: "100px" }} src='' />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3} className="center-mobile-text">
                    <div >
                        <h5>Name : {name}</h5>
                        <p> Location: {location}</p>
                        <p> Title : {title} </p>
                    </div>
                    <a style={{ color: "#007bb5" }} target="_blank" href="">
                        <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                            <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a style={{ color: "black" }} target="_blank" href="">
                        <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                            <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i className="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a style={{ color: "red" }} target="_blank" href="">
                        <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                            <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i className="fas fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col md={7}>
                    <p className="textStyle">{description}</p>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AboutMe;
```

And a JSON file in a Data Folder:

```
{
  "Name": "Test data",
  "Title": "Test data job",
  "Location": "Test data location",
  "Description": ""
}
```

Comment: 1.  what port is react running on?  what port is the C# code running on?  what is your cors policy and can react access the c# service?

Comment: React is running on 3000, the default. I'm unsure how to check the C# port? I don't know what a CORS policy is & why wouldn't react be able to access the service?

Answer (score 1):

First, inside your React component, change your useEffect from :

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
});
```

into :

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

In the first case, the useEffect will be executed each time the component is updated. So, fetchData will run forever (and freeze your page btw).

In the second case, the useEffect will be executed after the component is mount. So fetchDate will run only one time.

For the api, did you try with the route : api/aboutMe/GetAboutInfo ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I've changed the useEffect statement as suggested, I did have it as that at one point but kept swapping back to the class component to see if the functional component was the issue and I must have left it out. 

I've tried that route and it's still blank :/

Comment: Which status code do you have when you go on api/aboutMe ?

Comment: I don't think there is one? There is nothing returned in the console. The screen is just the empty site template with the Nav Bar.

Comment: In the dev tool you have a tab "Network" you should see your request there

Comment: I've added a photo in the post of what shows on Network, not sure if any are the API? This doesn't change when I change the URL to add /GetAboutInfo in the js & chrome.

Comment: the localhost:3000 is the port where your react app is running not the api. When you run your api with visual studio, a new window should be open. You can see there on which port your api is running

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry I'm new to this. Ok the API is running and works but there is still nothing coming through the react app on the /aboutMe page